# Positioning images in CSS

Tags: html, css, positioning

My goal is to position a Facebook and a Twitter button on my website, using CSS.
However, what I want doesn't seem to work.

[image]

The Twitter icon always sits below the Facebook icon. Also when I resize my browser's window the position of these buttons changes. What am I doing wrong? Here is my CSS:

```
#social {
   position: fixed;
   _position: absolute;
   z-index: 1000;
   left:70%;
   top: 120px;
   width: 100px;
   height: 50px;
}   

#social .facebook {
   float: left;
   width: 35px;
   height: 35px;
   padding: 0 0px 0 0px; /* top, right, bottom, left */
   margin: 0;
   list-style: none;
}

#social .twitter {
   float: left;
   width: 35px;
   height: 35px;
   padding: 0 0px 0 50px; /* top, right, bottom, left */
   margin: 0;
   list-style: none;
}

#social .facebook, .twitter li {
   list-style: none;
}

#social .facebook, .twitter li a {
   text-decoration: none;
}

#social .facebook, .twitter li a img {
   border: none;
}
```

The HTML:

```
<div id="social">  

<ul class="facebook">
<li><a href="http://www.facebook.com/"><img src="img/facebook-button.png" width="35"    height="35" alt="Facebook" title="Volg ons op Facebook" /></a></li>
</ul>    
<ul class="twitter">
<li><a href="http://www.twitter.com/"><img src="img/twitter-icon.png" width="35" height="35" alt="Twitter" title="Volg ons op Twitter" /></a></li>
</ul>

</div>
```

Comment: you'd better also post the HTML code, hard to answer your question if you only provide CSS

Comment: though i already see one mistake: .facebook should have float:left too...

Comment: HTML added, Float mistake added to the css.

Comment: I'm only saying this because I've been 'told off' for doing this myself... add your html as an edit to your main question :)

Comment: can you edit your post and add the html there? hard to read html if it's in a comment :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this?  (IANA css expert,  but I got this to look as I think you want it to look)

```
#social {
    z-index: 1000;
    float:right;
    margin-top:120px;
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
}   

#social .facebook {
    width:35px;
    float:left;
    height:35px;
    padding:0 0px 0 0px; /* top, right, bottom, left */
    margin: 0;
    list-style:none;
}

#social .twitter {
    float: left;
    width:35px;
    height:35px;
    padding:0 0px 0 px; /* top, right, bottom, left */
    margin: 0;
    list-style:none;
}

#social .facebook, .twitter li {
    list-style:none;
}

#social .facebook, .twitter li a {
    text-decoration:none;
}

#social .facebook, .twitter li a img {
    border: none;
}
```

I added a `float` to the `facebook` rule, removed the `50px` padding from the `twitter` rule.

**Edit:**  Mine works using divs.  but you use lists, so I think the nested list combination is causing yours to break.

```
<div id="social">
    <div class="facebook">
        <a href="o-vita.nl/">
            <img src="img/facebook-button.png" width="35" height="35" alt="Facebook" title="Volg ons op Facebook" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="twitter">
        <a href="o-vita.nl/">
            <img src="img/twitter-icon.png" width="35" height="35" alt="Twitter" title="Volg ons op Twitter" />
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Edit:  http://notails.com/development/positioningsocialnetworkingicons.html

Comment: Thank you MrVimes, at least the twitter icon is next to the facebook icon now :) However, this doesn't solve the problem of the changing position when i resisze my window... Do you have any solution for that one?

Comment: I'm not sure about that one.  When I resize my browser on the test page I created the container of the two images is 70% from the left and 120px from the top as per the css, but the images stay next to each other.

Comment: They do stay next to each other. But see what the images do when I resize my browser window: http://piclair.com/data/oc8wa.jpg

They don't stay within the black container.

Comment: ok.  Your CSS shows position absolute and 70% left, so your images are doing exactly that.  They are 'fixed' at a point 70% from the left side of your page. So when you resize your browser they move to where 70% from the left is according to your browser's new size.   Maybe replace the percentage with an absolute value?

Comment: This is getting beyond my ability with css, but I assume you want your images and the black box to always be 'attached' to the right side of the browser window?  Then maybe you need the containing element to be floated right.

Comment: Yeah, you got it. I want the images to be attached to the black box... It's frustrating to think that I've designed such things before.. But at the moment I can't remember how I did this before :(

Comment: With floating right I can get it to stay on the right side of the browser...

http://notails.com/development/positioningsocialnetworkingicons.html

I'll add that link to my post.

Comment: Okay, that works :) But what if you want to change the top value of the container? I have the icons here now: http://piclair.com/data/p3sbp.jpg But I want them in the black box :) If I change the top value, nothing happens..

Comment: I was able to change their height using margin-top:120px in the #social rule but I'm not sure what that will do to the rest of your page.

Comment: Ok, that works. But I'm affraid we have another problem.. Even if I set the margin-top to 0px, I couldn't get the icons at the appropriate height. This is because another div's is causing the trouble: http://piclair.com/data/dcysu.jpg

Comment: CSS gets difficult when things are floated :)   I *think* you can fix that by floating the div above it left.  But then you might break something else :)

Comment: Ahaha forgive me for being stupid :) It might not be the neatest solution but it works. I have now set the margin-top to -55 and margin-right to 160px :P Now it works in all major browsers!

Comment: No problem. Glad to help.  You can click the tick next to my answer to accept it :)

Comment: I tried that before, but I need more rep to do that. I'm still a newb here :)

Comment: The layout of that little widget is always expected to be exact. Why float the images? Why not `position: relative` on the container and `position: absolute` on the images? For that matter, why does each icon have its own `<ul>`? All you need is one div, two anchors (with images in each).

Answer (score 0):

Hm, can you show me the website? Because I need to know more information about your website structure, however you can try this.

Sorry for my English.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="social">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com/"><img src="img/facebook-button.png" width="35"    height="35" alt="Facebook" title="Volg ons op Facebook" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.twitter.com/"><img src="img/twitter-icon.png" width="35" height="35" alt="Twitter" title="Volg ons op Twitter" /></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#social {
  position:fixed;
  _position:absolute;
  z-index:1000;
  left:70%;
  top:120px;
  width:100px;
  height:50px;
}

#social ul{
  list-style:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

#social li{
  float:left;
  width:35px;
  height:35px;
  margin:0 3px;
}

#social a{
  text-decoration:none;
}

#social a img {
   border:none;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Fong-Wan Chau, but the problem is already solved. See the discussion above.